# How to find and delete a row if it's placed after another row within group variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've long format data and I'd like to delete every row from group 2 if it's placed after row from group 3 within each ID. For example:

```
ID group value
1  1     43
1  2     2
1  3     6
1  4     20
2  1     24
2  3     5
2  2     16
2  4     19
```

into:

```
ID group value
1  1     43
1  2     2
1  3     6
1  4     20
2  1     24
2  3     5
2  4     19
```

I stuck at:

```
data %>%
    group_by(id)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `slice` as below:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(
    if (any(which(group == 2) > which(group == 3))) 
      -which(group == 2)[which(group == 2) > which(group == 3)] 
    else 1:n()
    )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID group value
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1    43
2     1     2     2
3     1     3     6
4     1     4    20
5     2     1    24
6     2     3     5
7     2     4    19
```

This approach does not require that 2 immediately follows 3. There can also be multiple occurrences of 2 which would all get removed if they appear after 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach using `lead()` from `dplyr` and a flag variable for filtering. The `lead()` function allows comparing values and then you can set a condition for the group value equals to `2`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
dfnew <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Lead=lead(group),
         Flag=ifelse(Lead-group>1 & group==2,1,0)) %>%
  filter(Flag==0) %>% select(-c(Flag,Lead))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID group value
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1    43
2     1     2     2
3     1     3     6
4     1     4    20
5     2     1    24
6     2     3     5
7     2     4    19
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), value = c(43L, 2L, 6L, 20L, 24L, 
5L, 16L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lag()` from dplyr you can do the following.

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(lag = lag(group)) %>%
  filter(!(group == 2 & lag == 3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-lag)

#      ID group value
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1    43
# 2     1     2     2
# 3     1     3     6
# 4     1     4    20
# 5     2     1    24
# 6     2     3     5
# 7     2     4    19
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), group = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4), value = c(43, 2, 6, 20, 24, 5, 16, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice(setdiff(row_number(), intersect(match(2, group), match(3, lag(group)))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID group value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    43
#2     1     2     2
#3     1     3     6
#4     1     4    20
#5     2     1    24
#6     2     3     5
#7     2     4    19
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), group = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4), value = c(43, 2, 6, 20, 24, 5, 16, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```